# apply_requirements not working in Gitlab community edition

Tags: gitlab, terraform, devops, atlantis

#### Overview

We are using Gitlab community edition [15.4.6] and atlantis version [0.23.3], deployed using kubernetes statefulset. Atlantis does not evaluate the settings present in Server side config.

#### Reproduction Steps

After deploying to kubernetes, define the `ATLANTIS_REPO_CONFIG` environement variable.

Tried other methods too:

using repo only config atlantis.yaml

using ATLANTIS_REPO_CONFIG_JSON json config

using argument --require-approval

using argument for config file - --repo-config

I want to execute atlantis apply only when the PR is approved by one other user.Currently atlantis does not throws an error and continues the execution.

Is this the problem of gitlab community edition or am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 0):

See the upstream [issue #3258](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/issues/3258) and [PR #3277](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/pull/3277). The upcoming 0.23.4 release should resolve the issue. You can use the latest `dev` image for now for testing until the new release is out.

Images

- [dev-alpine-8adb001](https://github.com/orgs/runatlantis/packages/container/atlantis/81810073?tag=dev-alpine-8adb001)
- [dev-debian-8adb001](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/pkgs/container/atlantis/81809332?tag=dev-debian-8adb001)